# Want to find Highest Maximum number and Second Highest Maximum Number with their Index value

Tags: c#, arrays

This code finds the highest number and second highest number but gives the wrong index number, but only in some cases
When array values: {1,3,3,0,3}
When Array Values: {3,3,0,1,2}

If all are unique numbers then it gives an accurate answer with accurate index value; Where do I need to change the code to get accurate index value for above cases?

```
FirstMaxNumber=arrFindIndex[0];
SecondMaxNumber=arrFindIndex[0];
FirstMaxRatingIndex=0;
SecondMaxRatingIndex=0;

for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
{
     if (FirstMaxNumber <= arrFindIndex[i])
     {
         SecondMaxNumber = FirstMaxNumber;
         FirstMaxNumber = arrFindIndex[i];
         FirstMaxRatingIndex = i;
      }
      else if (SecondMaxNumber <= arrFindIndex[i])
      {
         SecondMaxNumber = arrFindIndex[i];
         SecondMaxRatingIndex = i;
      }
}

// print(FirstMaxNumber);
// Print(FirstMaxRatingIndex);

// print(SecondMaxNumber);
// print(SecondMaxRatingIndex);
```

Comment: Which language are you wanting an answer in? You have tagged 3 different programming languages

Comment: what type are your variables?

Comment: simple Integer data types only

Answer (score 1):

In the first if statement, the value of the second maximum value is set:

```
SecondMaxNumber = FirstMaxNumber;
```

but the index isn't:

```
SecondMaxRatingIndex = FirstMaxRatingIndex;
FirstMaxRatingIndex = i;
```

Comment: Yaa... Happening this, but where i can get  index value for second max number

Comment: Not understand, little confusing me

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
FirstMaxNumber = arrFindIndex[0];
SecondMaxNumber = arrFindIndex[0];

FirstMaxRatingIndex = 0;
SecondMaxRatingIndex = 0;

// Do not use magic values: "arrSize" but actual length: arrFindIndex.Length
for (int i = 1; i < arrFindIndex.Length; i++) {
  int v = arrFindIndex[i];

  if (v > FirstMaxNumber) {
    // so "first" becomes "second"
    SecondMaxNumber = FirstMaxNumber;
    SecondMaxRatingIndex = FirstMaxRatingIndex;

    FirstMaxNumber = v;
    FirstMaxRatingIndex = i;
  }
  else if ((v > SecondMaxNumber) || (i == 1)) {
    SecondMaxNumber = v;
    SecondMaxRatingIndex = i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use LINQ for that?

```
var arr = new [] {3, 0, 4, 2, 3, 7};
var min = arr.Select((Val, Key) => new { Val, Key }).First(x => x.Val == arr.Min());
var max = arr.Select((Val, Key) => new { Val, Key }).First(x => x.Val == arr.Max());

Console.WriteLine($"Min Key: {min.Key} Val: {min.Val} \nMax Key: {max.Key} Val: {max.Val}");

// Output
// Min Key: 1 Val: 0 
// Max Key: 5 Val: 7
```

Comment: I require manual code for finding Maximum Number and Second Highest number with their index value,  My code can find Highest and Second Highest number with thier index value, but it gives wrong answer for above mention cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays are short and you don't particularly care how fast it is, the easiest code is something like this:

```
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length).ToArray();
Array.Sort(array, indices, Comparer<int>.Create((a, b) => b - a));
```

Then `indices` will contain the indices of all the elements, in descending order, so you just need the first two.

Here's a compilable console app (requires .Net 4.5 or later):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            test(1, 3, 3, 0, 3); // Prints 1, 2
            test(3, 3, 0, 1, 2); // Prints 0, 1
        }

        static void test(params int[] array)
        {
            var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length).ToArray();
            Array.Sort(array, indices, Comparer<int>.Create((a,b)=>b-a));
            Console.WriteLine($"{indices[0]}, {indices[1]}");
        }
    }
}
```